# Adding lat/long coordinates to clicked feature on ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online

When I click a feature in my ArcGIS Online, I would like to customize the popup to display the latitude and longitude coordinates of the feature along with the fields for the feature that was clicked.

Can this be accomplished with ArcGIS Online?

Comment: This should be able to be done by adding a new calculated field with Arcade.  A discussion of doing similar to what you are trying to do is at https://community.esri.com/thread/199141-arcade-expression-for-geometry-in-arcgis-online-popup.

Answer (score 0):

That information would need to be in your data before publishing, then it can be viewed via the pop up